# TemplateDoesNotExist at / Exception Value: index.html django

Tags: python, html, django, templates, settings

welcome
i make a new project and i put index.html in templates dirctory and when i runserver i got the message TemplateDoesNotExist at / where the mistake i done

there is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

there is the urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    
]
```

and there is the sitting.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

the templates_dir and static_dir i add it after make project

Answer (score 0):

just add `TEMPLATES_DIR` inside TEMPLATES in settings.py file.

**Example:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR], #Added here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            
        },
    },
]
```

And see if it solves that error